# Android which is best, Room or Realm?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, realm, android-room

Please, can anyone help me choose the best ORM library to be used in a Messaging app like Whatsapp, I have two options to choose from, either [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) or [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-java), So which should I choose and what's the Pros and Cons for each library?